# Postgres - unable to get query result after transaction

Tags: typescript, postgresql, pg-promise, node-postgres

I'm using node and postgres to query and get result back. Inside a transaction I want to get data of first insert query. Below is my function:

```
const createStudent = (studentData) => {
 return db.query(
  `
    BEGIN;
    insert into student (fname, lname, email) values ($1, $2, $3) returning *;
    insert into studentbillingInfo (student_id, column1) values (curval('student_id_seq'), 'data');
    COMMIT;
  `, [values]
 )
.then(data => data)
.then (() => {
 return sendNotificationFunc()
 .catch((error) => throw error)
})
.catch((error) => throw error)
}
```

How do I get result back of first insert statement from `createStudent()` function ? Here my `data` variable is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd execute the first insert, get the result, then execute the second one. But if you don't want to do any processing on the results from the first query in the application, you can also use a CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE parent( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE child( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES parent(id));

WITH a AS (INSERT INTO parent (name) VALUES ('foo') RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO child (parent_id) SELECT id FROM a RETURNING *;

 id | parent_id
----+-----------
  1 |         1
```

In this example both tables have their own SERIAL column, so I putting both columns in the second insert's RETURNING clause to allow the application to get both ids.

Answer (score 0):

`pg-promise` has its own syntax for transactions...

```js
const createStudent = studentData => db.tx(async t => {
    const student = await t.one('insert into student(fname, lname, email) values($1, $2, $3) returning *');
    await t.none('insert into studentbillingInfo(student_id, column1) values(curval($1), $2)', ['student_id_seq', 'data']);
    return student;
});
```

And then...

```js
let studentData = 'whatever';
const student = await createStudent(studentData);
sendNotificationFunc();
```